# Request module throwing 403 without trying

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

I have a really weird problem.

I have two node.js servers running `express`, say A and B. I use `request` to send request from one A to B. Sometimes, the `request` module just throws `403` at me `Forbidden file type or location` without even sending a request to B.

I have multiple servers running same code, only one of the servers have this issue. Everyone else properly sends the request and shows response.

I did a tcpdump, no entries for communication between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by HTTP_PROXY settings I had in my systemd configuration.